# Upload multiple File in codeigniter After Submit form

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, multifile-uploader

In my CodeIgniter project, I'm uploading multiple files during the project creation. Please let me know how to upload multiple file using CI.

This is output array after submit form.

```
[user_attached] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [pic_passport] => cp-user-error.png
                    [att_document] => local-delivery-done.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [pic_passport] => image/png
                    [att_document] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [pic_passport] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC707.tmp
                    [att_document] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC718.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [pic_passport] => 0
                    [att_document] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [pic_passport] => 635392
                    [att_document] => 36512
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To Upload Multiple File in Codeigniter. Try this.

```
     $filesCount = count($_FILES['user_attached']['name']);
    $path = 'upload/document';
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    }
    $array = ['pic_passport','att_document'];

for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) { 

    $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['user_attached']['name'][$array[$i]];
    $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['user_attached']['name'][$array[$i]];
    $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['user_attached']['type'][$array[$i]];
    $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['user_attached']['tmp_name'][$array[$i]];
    $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['user_attached']['error'][$array[$i]];
    $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['user_attached']['size'][$array[$i]];
    $imagename = $this->randomAlphanumId(10);              
    $image_name[$array[$i]]="doc_".$imagename."_".str_replace(array(' '),'_',$_FILES['userFile']['name']);

    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['file_name'] = $image_name[$array[$i]];
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
        $fileData = $this->upload->data();
        $upload_image[] = $fileData['file_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/peb901
---
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: controllers/MainController.php

Line Number: 129

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\yard\application\controllers\MainController.php
Line: 129
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\yard\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: it's error because of your name array keys like `pic_passport` and `att_document` instead of `0` and `1`. @UsamaAshraf

Answer (score 0):

Create library for this code and call from controller

```
for($i = 0; $i < $config_array['files_count']; $i++)
{
    if($config_array['file_data']['name'][$i]) 
    {
        $file_name = $config_array['file_data']['name'][$i];

        $file_info  = pathinfo($file_name);

        $new_file_name = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '_', $file_info['filename']);

        $new_file_name = $new_file_name.'_'.DATE(UPLOAD_FILE_DATE_FORMAT);

        $new_file_name = str_replace('.','_',$new_file_name);

        $file_extension = $file_info['extension'];

        $new_file_name = $new_file_name.'.'.$file_extension;

        $_FILES['attchment']['name'] = $new_file_name;

        $_FILES['attchment']['tmp_name'] = $config_array['file_data']['tmp_name'][$i];

        $_FILES['attchment']['error'] = $config_array['file_data']['error'][$i];

        $_FILES['attchment']['size'] = $config_array['file_data']['size'][$i];

        $config['upload_path'] = $config_array['file_upload_path'];

        $config['file_name'] = $new_file_name;

        $config['allowed_types'] = $config_array['file_permission'];

        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;

        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        $config['max_size'] = $config_array['file_size'];

        $this->CI->load->library('upload',$config);

        $this->CI->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->CI->upload->do_upload('attchment'))
        {
            array_push($file_array,array(
                    'og_name'=> $file_name,
                    'name'=> $new_file_name)
            );
        }
        else
        {   
            array_push($error_msgs,$this->CI->upload->display_errors('',''));
        }
    }
}
```